# How to make sh script the application for Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, scripting, shell

I wrote java application and i need to make it standalone for macos(.app). Earlier I used jar builder, but now i need to execute some shell script before java application starts. How can i do it?

Comment: People still use MacOS? I thought OS X was the new hotness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a double-clickable application, you could use AppleScript to execute the shell script and then the application.  The AppleScript Editor allows you to save a script as a .app application.  Simplest thing that would work:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script with command "cd /Users/justin/Desktop; ./app.sh; java myApp"
end tell
```

File -> Save As, and choose "Application" under File Format.

EDIT: Even simpler, you could execute the shell script from within the java app... Depends on what you're trying to accomplish though.